A short story about a haunted room in a partially old mansion. Not "horror", the ghost does no harm
I read this fantasy short story in a collection about 20 years ago. Of course, it could be much older.
A rich man who has many friends likes having people around. But it happens that he invites too many people at the same time, and there are not enough rooms upstairs. So on a few occasions, he has to install one guest in a room downstairs in the only part of his mansion which is old, the remainder having been rebuilt.
In this story this situation happens. The woman who sleeps in that room is awakened by a sound. The door she has locked from the inside opens, a man walks in. She is terrorised, but the mysterious man in her room does not harm her in the least, just stays there a short time and leaves.
Because of the bad night she spent, she wakes up late and joins breakfast when most guests have left. Only the host and a single woman guest are still there. So the victim complains to the host who apologises and admits he knew this old part was haunted. Several guests have seen a ghost before her, three in all. He describes the experiences of two of them. But the victim does not believe it and accuses him of having played a practical joke on her.
Then the other woman tells her that her own description of what the man did proves he was a ghost. Indeed, she placed him in a certain place in the room respective to a window, IIRC, and if his torso had been there, then his legs would have occupied the same place as some solid piece of furniture. Asked how she knew that, she replied she had been the third person to notice the ghost when sleeping in that room.
EDIT
One detail that came back to my mind : at some point in the story, someone remarks that the ghost only appears to women. He is never seen by men who happen to sleep in the "haunted room".
IIRC, the title of the story has something to do with this particularity. "A ghost who preferred women" or something like that. But random search with such keywords led me nowhere.
